# printing from a json

Tags: python, json

I am trying to print out labels from a Json file. My program is currently only printing the last json file.

I'm trying to print out the name in a json file when I run the program. this is what i got so far

```
inventoryFileNames = ["REID_1F_20171004.json", "REID_2F_20171004.json", "REID_3F_20171004.json"]
itemNameToInventoryItem = {}

for inventoryFileName in inventoryFileNames: 
    inventoryFile = open( inventoryFileName, 'r' )
    inventoryData = json.loads( inventoryFile.read() )

while sortChoice != 'q':
    MachineSTock = input('Would you like the (m) machine report or the (i)inventory report?:')
    if MachineSTock == 'm':
        inventoryFile = open( inventoryFileName, 'r' )
        inventoryData = json.loads( inventoryFile.read() )
        print('Label              Pct Sold              Sales ' )    
        print (inventoryData['machine_label'], ":")
```

I expect it to print out:

```
Label              
REID_1F :
REID_2F :
REID_3F :
```

Comment: You are defining inventoryFilenames inside a loop that is looping through elements in inventoryFilenames. That will produce an error, as inventoryFilenames is not defined when the 'for' statement references it. Are you sure you have provided the correct code? I

Comment: def main():
    inventoryFileNames = ["REID_1F_20171004.json", "REID_2F_20171004.json", "REID_3F_20171004.json"]
    itemNameToInventoryItem = {}while sortChoice != 'q':
          
        MachineSTock = input('Would you like the (m) machine report or the (i)inventory report?:')

Comment: ####ok so here is the code that i have to push out the three names.######       while sortChoice != 'q':
          
        MachineSTock = input('Would you like the (m) machine report or the (i)inventory report?:')
        
        if MachineSTock == 'm':
            
                inventoryFile = open( inventoryFileName, 'r' )
                inventoryData = json.loads( inventoryFile.read() )
                    

        print('Label              Pct Sold              Sales ' )    
        print (inventoryData['machine_label'], ":")  the machine label prints out 1 of the 3 names

Comment: Define inventoryFileNames above for loop

Comment: Would you please edit the original question so it's formatted properly?

Comment: Im new to python and this board so I apologize about the confusion. I hope my edit to the original question is clear now

Comment: Where did you even define `inventoryFileName` (without an `s` at the end)?

Comment: it was a for loop after the json names. I just didnt want to overload the question with all the code but i guess i should have added it.

Comment: It prints only the last json file because inside the file read loop you assign `inventoryData` to the current file's contents, which discards the previous value of `inventoryData`.

Comment: Any ideas what needs to go in there instead of inventory data? I thought I tried them all

Answer (score 1):

The issue has nothing to do with json. If you want to loop over all the files and print something from each, then your `print` statement needs to be inside your `for` loop.

Try this. I've removed some of the aspects unrelated to your question.

```
inventoryFileNames = ["REID_1F_20171004.json", "REID_2F_20171004.json", "REID_3F_20171004.json"]
itemNameToInventoryItem = {}

print('Label              Pct Sold              Sales ' )    

for inventoryFileName in inventoryFileNames: 
    inventoryFile = open( inventoryFileName, 'r' )
    inventoryData = json.loads( inventoryFile.read() )

    print (inventoryData['machine_label'], ":")
```

Notice how the first `print` is "outside" (above and at the same indentation level) the `for` loop and the second `print` is now "inside" (indented and under) the `for` loop? That means that the first `print` statement will execute once to give you the headings, while the second `print` statement will execute for every item in `inventoryFileNames`.

If you maintain that structure, you can put your `input` command back in. Just ask yourself - do you want to `input` once (if so put it outside the `for` loop) or for every item in `inventoryFileNames` (if so put it inside the `for` loop)?

Comment: Heath......you are freaking GOD!!!! fixed it right on up!!!! IM new to code and Im always doing stuff backward. Ill have the elemnts there but my my order is always jacked up. Im learning. Thanks guy!!!